# Dialog that can be use in winform and wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Good day.

I created a dll. In this library i need to embed a dialog(which shows some values on textbox) which can run on windows form and wpf . i use winform in my dll but the problem is i can't show the dialog in wpf. i can't use Messagebox because i have a multiline textbox for user input.

Here is the screenshot of my dialog

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you used when you tried to open the dialog from WPF?

Answer (score -1):

you can use WindowsFormsHost, here is a doc tell you how to use this:
[Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-windows-forms-control-in-wpf)

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: This answer does not fully answer the original question. The WindowsFormsHost is for hosting a WinForms control on top of WPF, not having a full blown dialog that can be used by both WinForms and WPF.